# BGP Collector and Vantage Point relationship

Tags: bgp

I am currently reading a paper *BGPStream: A Software Framework for Live and Historical BGP Data Analysis* where authors say:

> Normally, a BGP session with a collector is configured as a
>   customer-provider relationship, i.e., as if the VP was offering
>   transit service to the collector

In a later part, authors desscribe popular projects offering route collectors:

> (...) currently operate 18 and 13 collectors respectively, which in
>   total peer with approximately 380 and 600 VPs distributed worldwide

I am not sure I understand it. VPs and collectors are peering, but they establish a customer-provider BGP session ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each vantage point treats the collector as if it is a BGP speaking customer, so the vantage point provides the collector with a full routing table. That way, the collector receives a full view of how the VP sees the internet.